# Is the frequency at which a species mutate affected by natural selection?

Tags: evolution, natural-selection, mutations

As per natural selection, is it safe to assume that some species will have it genetically encoded so that they produce a certain 'perfect' rate of mutation so that they can adapt to an environment that changes quickly?

Another way to put this; does every type of organisms have  roughly the same amount of mutations each time they reproduce (relative to the size of their DNA)? If so, is/can/could this be governed by natural selection?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has there been any observation of species adapting the evolution process?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/378/has-there-been-any-observation-of-species-adapting-the-evolution-process)

Answer (score 1):

**Drake's rule**

Let $L$ be the size of the genome. Let $\mu$ be the average per nucleotide mutation rate, then the genome-wide mutation rate $U$ is $U=L \mu$. There is a general relationship between the genome size of an organism and the nucleotide mutation rate that makes that the genome-wide mutation rate is often approximatively 1. There is of course several orders of magnitude of variation around this value of 1 among organisms.

This rule is called Drake's rule after the name of the author who first discovered it ([Drake, 1991](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC52253/)).

To my knowledge, this relationship is not fully well understood. Because you are looking for an adapted mutation rate in your question, I would like to highlight that I would not go about assuming this is adaptive. I could imagine that some molecular genetic constraint of the replication process could be causing this type of relationship between $L$ and $\mu$.

You will probably want to read [this post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/23711/drakes-law-what-is-the-genome-wide-mutation-rate-and-what-are-the-estimates) about Drake's rule.

**Mutation rate in humans**

In humans, the average mutation rate is estimated to be around $\mu=2.5 \cdot 10^{-8}$ ([Nachman and Crowell, 2000](http://www.genetics.org/content/genetics/156/1/297.full.pdf); see also [this post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/65204/how-much-variation-in-mutation-rate-in-there-in-the-human-genome)), with a genome size of about $L=3 \cdot 10^9$, leading to an estimate of the genome-wide mutation rate of 80.

Interestingly, the mutation rate is in fathers is age-dependent. See the post [Gender and age-specific mutation rate in plants](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/19908/gender-and-age-specific-mutation-rate-in-plants).